# TypeError: must be str, not int -- Python error

Tags: python

```
def absolutevalue(num):
        if num >= 0:
            abs_num = num
        else:
            abs_num = -num
        print("The absolute value"+ abs_num)
```

If I try to run the function `absolutevalue(4)`, it throws error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-36bd355eb83d>", line 1, in <module>
    absolutevalue(4)

  File "<ipython-input-15-42a3de37c325>", line 6, in absolutevalue
    print("The absolute value"+ abs_num)

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("The absolute value"+ abs_num)
```

Python is giving you an error in this line because you can use `+` operator only to ***concatenate two string or add two integers together***. ***You can't add integer to a string or concatenate an string with integer***. It's bad syntax in Python.

You can fix this by using the string version of the integer.

```
print("The absolute value"+ str(abs_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
print("The absolute value"+ abs_num)
```

to be

```
print("The absolute value", abs_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient and quick way to do this is:

```
print("The absolute value {}".format(abs_num))
```

And in the latest version of Python which is 3.7 we have formatted strings now:

```
print(f'The absolute value {abs_num}')
```